# Adding an ID to Mapbox Marker

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet, mapbox

I am trying to add an `id` to each marker so that I can trigger a modal window when the marker is clicked using JQuery instead of the built in popup functionality. I want to populate the `id` with the property "id".

I know that I need recursively go through and add the ids but I'm not about how to achieve this. How do I go about doing this?

```
var geojson = [{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
    "coordinates": [-86.781602, 36.162664],
    "type": "Point"
  },
  "properties": {
    "id": 001,
    "title": "POI #1",
    "image": "http://lorempixel.com/image_output/city-h-c-524-822-2.jpg",
    "filter-1": true,
    "filter-2": false,
    "filter-3": false,
    "filter-4": true,
    "filter-5": false,
    "marker-color": "#1087bf",
    "marker-size": "medium",
    "marker-symbol": ""
  }
}];
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8h58qpny/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do a `for` loop. [I've updated your fiddle with the correct code](https://jsfiddle.net/8h58qpny/1/) to cycle through the length of your `geojson` variable, add a new field called `propertiesID`, then sets that to `properties` plus the `id` field, so you get `properties1`, `properties2`, etc.

The code change can be found on line 90 of the fiddle

```
for (var i=0; i<geojson.length; i++){
    geojson[i].properties.propertiesID = "properties" + geojson[i].properties.id

    //Logs out each object's properties in your array
    console.log(geojson[i].properties)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a quick hack using Mapbox GL JS. I created a default marker and just want a quick way to change the cursor, without doing extra coding.

Here is the code to create the marker:

```
this.marker = new mapboxgl.Marker({
  draggable: true,
  color: "#D80739",
}).setLngLat(centre);
```

I added an ID to it with:

```
this.marker._element.id = "my-marker";
```

And then style with with a CSS ID selector:

```
#my-marker {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

May not be an efficient solution but here it is.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jz08vuo4/)

```
for (var key in geojson) {
  if (geojson.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    // console.log(key + " -> " + geojson[key]);
    var poi = geojson[key];
    var marker_id = poi.properties.id;
    var latitude = poi.geometry.latitude;
    var longitude = poi.geometry.longitude;
    var filterOne = poi.properties.filterOne;

    // render marker
    markers[poi.properties.id] = L.marker([latitude, longitude],{
      filterOne: poi.properties.filterOne,
      filterTwo: poi.properties.filterTwo,
      filterThree: poi.properties.filterThree,
      name: poi.properties.name
    }).addTo(map);

    //assign id
    markers[poi.properties.id]._icon.id = poi.properties.id;
  }
}
```